# What kind of threshold should I have between up-voting, down-voting, and "not-voting"?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

I decided to take a look at my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol) on SO, and I get the impression that "I'm doing it wrong" with regard to up/down votes.

I feel like, if I have 6,000+ answers, 1,500 total votes seems like a lousy amount to have.

Now, while I do have a few more upvotes than downvotes, I tend to find myself looking at the vote buttons and either going "this is a crap question, downvote it", or "eh... it's a decent question, but is it upvote-worthy?"

I feel like I'm being overly conservative with my votes.

Is there any way to find out how my voting compares to that of users in general? And what, if anything, should I change about my voting attitude to improve?

Comment: It looks like an overall rate up/down of 10 is on par: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194505/overall-voterate

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of either linked question; it's about total voting rate, not specifically upvotes or downvotes.

Comment: @mmyers agreed but I prefer not using my hammer for this, sorry!